# Mastermind/Bulls and Cows game checkguess in Python

Tags: python

I've found 2 issues with my function that checks my guesses.

1) Suppose the code is [2,3,4,5] and [0,0,0,2], I think the correct response should be 0B 1C, but I get 0B 3C instead.

2) When I input [0,0,0,0] as a guess, I get an Index Error, 'list index out of range'. =[ Not sure why.

My code below:

```
def checkGuess1(code, guess):
    i = 0
    countB = 0
    countC = 0
    while i < len(code):
        if code[i] == guess[i]:
            countB = countB + 1
        else:
            for j in code:
                if code[i] == guess[j] and i != j :
                    countC = countC + 1
        i = i + 1

    print "A: " + str(countB)
    print "B: " + str(countC)
    return countB, countC

#------------- TEST CASE -----------------------
code = [2,3,4,5]
guess = [0,2,2,2]
guess1 = [0,0,0,0]
checkGuess1(code, guess)
checkGuess1(code, guess1)
```

Thanks for your time and help! Take Care!

Comment: I get a `TypeError` on `checkGuess1('2345', '0222')`, because `j` is a string and therefore not a valid string index.

Comment: Why not name `arg1` and `arg2` more descriptively?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The first step in debugging almost every programming problem is to create a minimal testcase. Please create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem (raises the `IndexError` you described) and contains *everything* needed for us to copy and paste it into a `*.py` file and run it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Sorry, when I input the arguments they are in list form. So instead of '2345' when it is inputted it will be [2,3,4,5]. I'll mention that, thanks!

Comment: @rockysock exactly to avoid that kind of confusion you should create an example that contains *everything* needed to run it.

Comment: so you should probably enter [0,0,0,0] instead of '0000'

Comment: @LukasGraf: Thanks for your comments, I couldn't see where to upload my *.py file onto the post so I just added a few more lines. And I noted your second comment regarding confusion, and edited the page accordingly or tried to, let me know what else I should be doing. Thanks!

Comment: @IanAuld: Sorry its a habit of mine to use arg1, arg2, etc... I've changed it on the code above. Thanks!

Comment: @rockysock I didn't mean for you to upload `*.py` files - including the example in the question like you did is exactly right. And now that you added the test case, it's perfect :)

Comment: @LukasGraf: Got it, thanks! My mistake, I misread your comment regarding the *.py file.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is here

```
for j in code:
```

this iterates over the elements in the code ... not the indices ... but later you say

```
if code[i] == guess[j] and i != j : 
              ^ 
              j will be 2, then 3,then 4, then 5 ... guess has no indice 4 or 5
```

however you can implement this whole thing much better as follows

```
def checkGuess(code,guess):
    bulls = sum(c1==c2 for c1,c2 in zip(code,guess))
    cows =  sum(c1 != c2 and c2 in code for c1,c2 in zip(code,guess))
    return bulls,cows
```

Is much nicer code to do this

here is an implementation that makes it more clear what is going on

```
def  checkGuess(code,guess):
     bulls = cows = 0 # no bulls or cows yet
     for code_char,guess_char in zip(code,guess): #pairs up the letters
         if code_char == guess_char: #match , bull
            bulls = bulls + 1
         elif guess_char in code:# no match but the item is in the code, cow
            cows = cows + 1
     return bulls,cows

print checkGuess("1234","5464")
#or
print checkGuess([1,2,3,4],[4,4,4,4])
```

Comment: Hello Joran with your implementation I no longer get the issue when my guess leads with a 0 results in an error =]. I'm still not sure why my implementation has that issue and will continue to look into it. But thank you very much for your help!